# How to use Cardboard vr view with no 360 content

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, unity-webgl

I have been searching for a way to build my unity google cardboard game for web, and I came across with this google vr view. But is this only for 360 content, with the 360 panorama asset ?

I have tried also to build the project for webgl but it doesn't work ( I think it has some compatibility issues with the cardboard SDK ).

Is there any other way to do so ? I want to load my vr game in a website and being able to see it both: with the cardboard and without them.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: I mean, the fundamental difference between web and VR is the camera that you put into unity.  Would it be difficult to copy the scripts from your VR camera and copy it onto a "Main Camera"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can build a game for web in unity that has support for webgl and cardboard, at least not at the moment.

I would suggest that you try something like Three.js and HTML5 to reach such ends. Check this link on a [Tutorial+Example](https://www.sitepoint.com/bringing-vr-to-web-google-cardboard-three-js/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I dont think that is possible with Unity. I found that sketchfab has a great section on VR that allows to see each model with cardboard ( that's the image I have added to the post ) . I would like something like that but not only for 360 panoramas but also for full games or scenes.

Comment: What i said is that you can't do it using unity! You can develop games with HTML5 and with Three.js you can implement the cardboard view such as sketchfab.